# How to disable highlight line in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

[MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) - linechart

[image]

how to invisible touching line ? 
please help.

Comment: setDrawGridLines(boolean enabled): Set this to true to enable drawing the grid lines for the axis

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar try to setDrawGridLines(false); this method is not success. I'm try         lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        lineChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        lineChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        lineChart.setDrawGridBackground(false); --- All fail.
more solution?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Actually its Highlight selected axis.

to remove that use `mChart.getData().setHighlightEnabled(false);`

**setHighlightEnabled** :  *Enables / disables highlighting values for all DataSets this data object contains. If set to true, this means that values can be highlighted programmatically or by touch gesture.*

---

If you have sample of MP Android Lib then you can check it from Option Menu named **"Toggle Highlight"**.

This can also be found in the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Highlighting).

Comment: I had to just unselect the selection and this is what worked for me `chart.highlightValues(null);`

Answer (score 49):

If still want to show marker, and hide those lines, try this. (MPAndroidChart v3.0.0)

`dataSet.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false);` `dataSet.setDrawVerticalHighlightIndicator(false);`

Answer (score 27):

To remove touch lines you can use

```
dataSet.setDrawHighlightIndicators(false);
```

To remove individual indicator lines, use either one of following

```
dataSet.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false);
dataSet.setDrawVerticalHighlightIndicator(false);
```

In this, 'dataSet' should be an instance of [LineScatterCandleRadarDataSet](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineScatterCandleRadarDataSet.java) (LineDataSet extending that class in the inheritance hierarchy)

You do not need to have mpAndroidChart Version 3. I tried this with version 2.1.6